# how to access IApplicationBuilder in a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac

Just wondering, is that possible to access IApplicationBuilder propteries outside of the startup.cs? Like in a controller?

I know it's only used to define the app pipeline so what would be the solution? Something like register a service that packages the instance, then inject the service instead of the IApplicationBuilder?

I'm trying to get back my DbConext from Autofac. Code is as following :

In `Business` project :

```
 public class AutofacBusinessModule : Autofac.Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacDataModule());
        }
    }
```

In Data project :

```
 public class AutofacDataModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<AppDbContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        }
    }
```

The `DbContext` :

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        private const string DbContextName = "AppDbConnectionString";
        public DbSet<Contest> Contests { get; set; }

        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public AppDbContext()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (optionsBuilder.IsConfigured) return;

            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();
            var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString(DbContextName);
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                x => x.MigrationsAssembly("Cri.CodeGenerator.Data"));
        }

        public virtual void Commit()
        {
            base.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

And the `ConfigureServices` in `startup.cs` in Web project :

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{


    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

   builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacBusinessModule());


    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();

    services.AddScoped(sp => {
        var actionContext = sp.GetRequiredService<IActionContextAccessor>().ActionContext;
        var urlHelperFactory = sp.GetRequiredService<IUrlHelperFactory>();
        var urlHelper = urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(actionContext);
        return urlHelper;
    });

    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
    builder.Populate(services);

    ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();

    //return the IServiceProvider implementation
    return new AutofacServiceProvider(ApplicationContainer);

}
```

I'm surely missing something, but really newbie when it comes to DI and .net core...

-- EDIT --

In my `Controller`

```
  private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
        private readonly IApplicationBuilder _app;


        private const int NumberOfCharactersRepetion = 4;

        public UniqueCodesController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment, IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
            _app = app;
        }
```

...

```
if (selectedAnswer == FileExtension.XLSX.GetStringValue())
                {
                    await FilesGenerationUtils.GenerateExcelFile(_app, uniqueCodesHashSet, model);
                }
```

in the `GenerateExcelFile` method :

```
public static async Task GenerateExcelFile(IApplicationBuilder app, IEnumerable<string> hashSetCodes, ContestViewModel model)
        {
...

 try
                    {
                        var context = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();

                        var contest = new Contest
                        {
                            Name = model.ProjectName,
                            UserId = 1,
                            FileGenerationStatus = true,
                            FilePath = fileInfo.FullName
                        };
                        context.Contests.Add(contest);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }

}
```

But when I run the app, I get this message :

```
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder' while attempting to activate 'Cri.CodeGenerator.Web.Controllers.UniqueCodesController'.
```

Comment: Usually when you have something registered in DI, you add it as a parameter to the constructor, so your controller's constructor in this case.

Comment: Usually you would put the dependency in the constructor of the controller and let the DI container resolve it. Is that not working? Where exactly are you thinking you need an IApplicationBuilder? You haven't shown this so it's a little difficult to understand the issue. If you have tried this and it didn't work, give more details on that, for example was there an exception or some other unexpected behavior? Everything you have here looks reasonable at first glance.

Comment: @MikeZboray I've just updated the original post to show what i'm trying to do and what I get when trying. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to get a new instance of `AppDbContext`.

If you have to keep the `GenerateExcelFile()` as `static` and want to reuse `AppDbContext` via a parameter,  you could make it accept an instance of `AppDbContext` instead of the `IApplicationBuilder`.

Firstly, simply inject such a service instance directly:

```
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
    private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;

    // ...

    public UniqueCodesController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment, AppDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
```

And then change the `GenerateExcelFile()` to accept a parameter of `AppDbContext`

```
    public static async Task GenerateExcelFile(IApplicationBuilder app, IEnumerable<string>hashSetCodes, ContestViewModel model)
    public static async Task GenerateExcelFile(AppDbContext dbContext, IEnumerable hashSetCodes, ContestViewModel model)
    {
        ...

        try{
            var context = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService();
            var contest = new Contest
            {
                Name = model.ProjectName,
                UserId = 1,
                FileGenerationStatus = true,
                FilePath = fileInfo.FullName
            };
            context.Contests.Add(contest);
            context.Contests.Add(contest);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Finally, you could invoke it as below :

```
    await FilesGenerationUtils.GenerateExcelFile(_dbContext, uniqueCodesHashSet, model);
```

---

As a side note, if you can't determine the required type at compile-time, and want to resolve some service type dynamically, **you could inject an `IServiceProvider` instead of the `IApplicationBuilder`**. In this way, You could resolve any instance as you like :

```
    var dbContext= sp.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
    // or if you need a service only available within a scope 
    using(var scope = this._sp.CreateScope()){
        var _anotherDbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
        ...
    }
```

Taking your code as an example, you could pass an `IServiceProvider` to `GenerateExcelFile(IServiceProvider sp, IEnumerable<string> hashSetCodes, ContestViewModel model)`, and within the `GenerateExcelFile()` method, you could resolve the `AppDbContext` in the following way:

```
    public static async Task GenerateExcelFile(IServiceProvider sp, IEnumerable<string> hashSetCodes, ContestViewModel model)
    {
        ...

        var dbContext= sp.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();

        try{
            var contest = new Contest
            {
                Name = model.ProjectName,
                UserId = 1,
                FileGenerationStatus = true,
                FilePath = fileInfo.FullName
            };

            dbContext.Contests.Add(contest);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Wow, that's a well constructed answer, thanks a lot for that! I've tried to inject an `IServiceProvider` as you mentioned, to resolve the `AppDbContext`but when it comes to `dbContext.Contests.Add(contest);`, I get this `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\appsettings.json'.` ... Any clue?

Comment: @j0w I notice that you're assuming the `appsettings.json` resides in the current directory when running in IIS. For some reason, your current directory is `'C:\Program Files\IIS Express`. I don't think there will be a `C:\Program Files\IIS Express\appsettings.json` file. As a result, it throws. Without the code,  I not sure why your current directory is changed to `C:\Program Files\IIS Express`. However, it's possible to use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`  to get the base location.

Comment: Just find out I was launching the project on `IIS` instead of the `web project`, and that's why the directory was not the good one. For now, i'll just launch the web project and i'll try later to laucj with IIS getting back the `appsettings.json` from there if possible. Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 2):

NO, it is not possible as far as I know.

You will have to write a middleware (or some other code) to get the data from IApplicationBuilder to HttpContext instance.

Then HttpContext instance you can access from inside the controllers.

Hope this helps.