# .NET Core Middleware - access IApplicationBuilder in a controller?

Tags: asp.net-core, httpcontext

I need to access IApplicationBuilder inside a controller.

**What I have tried :-**

I have written middleware (app.UseMyMiddleware) as follows

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseMyMiddleware();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
public class MyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        ///TODO - Pass IApplicationBuilder to HttpContext 
        await _next(context);
    }
}
public static class MiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

but I can't figure out how I can pass IApplicationBuilder to HttpContext in *Invoke* method. so, that I can use it in a controller.
I have also referred following stackoverflow question-answer

1. [how to access IApplicationBuilder in a controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55462128/how-to-access-iapplicationbuilder-in-a-controller)
2. [.Net Core Middleware - Getting Form Data from Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56055131/net-core-middleware-getting-form-data-from-request)

**Question(s) :-**

1. How can pass IApplicationBuilder to HttpContext in *Invoke* method to use it in controller?
2. Is there any better way to access IApplicationBuilder inside controller apart from middleware?

Comment: `IApplicationBuilder` is designed to build the app at the starting-up time, run once and not for running at runtime later. So I don't think it can provide you any ***runtime*** services or apis, what do you want about it? That's more important than how to have it available.

Comment: @KingKing I would like to configure Hangfire in controller using this IApplicationBuilder. you can refer question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66022553/configuring-hangfire-in-net-core-2-1 for more details

Comment: you cannot access `IApplicationBuilder` anywhere later but you can plug-in middlewares at runtime using `UseWhen`. However the filter condition cannot take advantage of your `MVC model binding` because you have just the `HttpContext` as the input, extract the request data from raw sources (query string, route data, headers, form, request body) by yourself. You can somehow implement a settings remembering or sending the selected option per each request).

Comment: @KingKing Could you please give me example how can I get this?

Comment: I've just added an example as required, it should work for your purpose. BTW, I've just edited it a bit just in case you'd seen it before.

Comment: @KingKing Thanks! for your effort I will check & let you know.

Answer (score 1):

IApplicationBuilder was not designed to work the way you want it to. Instead, if you have some data created at build time that you want to be available to middleware add a Singleton to the services and inject the singleton into the middleware.

Comment: Thanks  for information. Is there any other work-around to solve this problem? I have tried KingKing approach provided in following answer but using that I can't change  "app.UseHangfireDashboard" configuration based on "builder.UseWhen" condition.(It configure only when application start).

Comment: It would be helpful to see an example of how you intend to use the IApplicationBuilder in a controller. If you show me I might be able to provide you with a work-around.

Comment: @Developer I'm pretty sure you don't know how to apply my solution, `.UseWhen` is the only option you can try. But looks like you don't need to solve it, ok fine. Many users have their final solution by responding back & forth, but you simply keep silence so there is no chance for others to help. That's just your choice.

Comment: @KingKing extremally sorry for delayed in response. I have used your solution but using that I can't change hangfire configuration (means hangfire connection string) based on condition (using .UseWhen). Now, I have added my answer. Thanks for your efforts and sorry for delayed in response.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access `IApplicationBuilder` anywhere later after completing the application building phase (after running `Configure` method). It's not available for injection at all.
However for the purpose of plugging-in or configuring middlewares at runtime based on request data (from `HttpContext`), you can use `.UseWhen`. Another one for terminal middleware is `.MapWhen` but I think that's not for your case. Here is an example of `.UseWhen`:

```
public static class MiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        var allOptions = new [] {"option 1","option 2"};
        foreach(var option in allOptions){
            var currentOption = option;
            builder.UseWhen(context => {
              //suppose you can get the user's selected option from query string
              var selectedOption = context.Request.Query["option_key"];
              return selectedOption == currentOption;
            }, app => {
               //your MyMiddleware is supposed to accept one argument
               app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>(currentOption);
            });
        }
        return builder;
    }
}
```

To simplify it I suppose your options are just strings, you must know beforehand all possible options that the user can select via UI. Each one will be an exact match for the condition to plug-in a middleware and they must be all exclusive (so just one of them can enable one corresponding middleware), otherwise there will be duplicate middlewares, which may cause some issue.

By expressing the `foreach` above more clearly, it may represent something as follows:

```
//kind of pseudo code
if(selectedOption1){
    app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>("option 1");
} else if(selectedOption2){
    app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>("option 2");
}
...
```

You must decide how you get the selected option from the user (in the example above I get it from `query string`). You can get it from `Cookie` as well (to remember the user's selection) or from other sources such as route data, headers, form, request body. I think  that's another issue, so if you have problem with that, please ask in another question.

Answer (score 0):

First up all thanks to @Kingking and @GlennSills for there solution and valuable comments.

I have solved this problem as

Created one class which inherit from *Hangfire.JobStorage* as follows

```
public class HangfireSqlServerStorageExtension : Hangfire.JobStorage
{
    private readonly HangfireSqlServerStorage _hangfireSqlServerStorage = new HangfireSqlServerStorage();

    public HangfireSqlServerStorageExtension(string nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        _hangfireSqlServerStorage.SqlServerStorageOptions = new SqlServerStorageOptions();
        _hangfireSqlServerStorage.SqlServerStorage = new SqlServerStorage(nameOrConnectionString, _hangfireSqlServerStorage.SqlServerStorageOptions);
    }
    public HangfireSqlServerStorageExtension(string nameOrConnectionString, SqlServerStorageOptions options)
    {
        _hangfireSqlServerStorage.SqlServerStorageOptions = options;
        _hangfireSqlServerStorage.SqlServerStorage = new SqlServerStorage(nameOrConnectionString, _hangfireSqlServerStorage.SqlServerStorageOptions);
    }

    public void UpdateConnectionString(string nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        _hangfireSqlServerStorage.SqlServerStorage = new SqlServerStorage(nameOrConnectionString, _hangfireSqlServerStorage.SqlServerStorageOptions);
    }

    public override IStorageConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return _hangfireSqlServerStorage.SqlServerStorage.GetConnection();
    }

    public override IMonitoringApi GetMonitoringApi()
    {
        return _hangfireSqlServerStorage.SqlServerStorage.GetMonitoringApi();
    }
}
```

**HangfireSqlServerStorage.cs**

Used in HangfireSqlServerStorageExtension class above

```
public class HangfireSqlServerStorage
{
    public SqlServerStorage SqlServerStorage { get; set; }
    public SqlServerStorageOptions SqlServerStorageOptions { get; set; }
}
```

***Startup.cs***

In Startup file add singleton service for HangfireSqlServerStorageExtension instance and configure hangfire dashboard as follows

```
public class Startup
{
    ///Other necessary code here
    
    public static HangfireSqlServerStorageExtension HangfireSqlServerStorageExtension { get; private set; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       ///Other necessary code here
       
        HangfireSqlServerStorageExtension = new HangfireSqlServerStorageExtension("DBConnecttionString"));
        services.AddSingleton<HangfireSqlServerStorageExtension>(HangfireSqlServerStorageExtension);
        services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration.SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170));
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
       //Other necessary code here

        app.UseHangfireDashboard("/Dashboard", new DashboardOptions(), HangfireSqlServerStorageExtension);

        //Other necessary code here
    }
}
```

Inside controller I have used it as follows

***HangfireController.cs***

```
public class HangfireController : Controller
{
   protected readonly HangfireSqlServerStorageExtension 
   hangfireSqlServerStorageExtension;

public HangfireController(HangfireSqlServerStorageExtension hangfireSqlServerStorageExtension)
{
    this.hangfireSqlServerStorageExtension = hangfireSqlServerStorageExtension;
}

public IActionResult DisplayHangfireDashboard()
{
    // Update connString as follows
    hangfireSqlServerStorageExtension.UpdateConnectionString(connString);
    var hangfireDashboardUrl = $"{this.Request.Scheme}://{this.Request.Host}{this.Request.PathBase}" + "/Dashboard";
    return Json(new { url = hangfireDashboardUrl });
}
}
```